# JavaScript MDN Tutorial - Example about floating point imprecision

Tags: javascript

So I am looking at the JavaScript MDN re-intro tutorial and got to the point on Floating Point Imprecision.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Why do they use this example?  Wouldn't you get that result in most all languages?

[image]

Comment: Some languages try to hide those problems from the user. JavaScript doesn't. Anyways, why would you take another example, if this simple one fits already?

Comment: @Sirko he wants to say the example isn't specific to javascript, he instead wants an example that works in other languages but not in javascript

Comment: Right, and since it specifically says, "if you're used to math in C or Java. Watch out for stuff like:" I would think that is the example they would give.  I am trying to make sure I am not missing something here.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @j08691 that's why "if you're used to math in C or Java" sentence is wrong :)

Comment: @niceman Right, because I am used to math in C or Java, and the example they posted looks normal to me.

Comment: hmmm on second thought timbram, notice the dot after that sentence, I think that suggests they don't link java or C to the example but rather to the fact that javascript doesn't have integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the documentation is just poorly structured. We have:

**"There's no such thing as an integer in JavaScript, so you have to be a little careful with your arithmetic if you're used to math in C or Java."**

This makes sense.  Then we have:

**"Watch out for stuff like: 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004"**

This also makes sense (as a general warning).

I think the documentation indented to have these as separate thoughts, but with the current formatting, it might taken as a a warning about floats specifically for C and Java programmers.

Comment: Ah okay that makes some sense. I was so confused at first glance!